# Can I have only one controller for multiple portlets in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I Have 10 different sub-portlets in one portlet. In portlet.xml file my configuration is::

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>portletA</portlet-name>
    <display-name>portletA</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-template</name>
        <value>/view-a.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>A</title>
        <short-title>A</short-title>
        <keywords>A</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>PortletB</portlet-name>
    <display-name>PortletB</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-template</name>
        <value>/view-b.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>B</title>
        <short-title>B</short-title>
        <keywords>B</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
```

Like this way. In my functionality, only view is different and in controller I have to write same code for all portlets.
In View's I have to write one action method this would be same for all the portlets. How can I achieve this. I was thinking to write the @doview but m not sure in this case what would be my portlet classes and how can I send different actions to same class.

Comment: You mean you have 10 different _portlets_ in one _plugin_? The answer to _Can I have only one controller for multiple portlets in liferay_ is _yes_, but I don't see what your problem is? Did you try to implement it the way you described it and ran into issues?

Comment: I just wanted to know what should be the value of 'Portlet-class' Do I need to write separate classes for each portlet?

Comment: @Nisha absolutely not... it is very common to have the same class declared as portal-class (as Tobias wrote, Liferay will create different instances per portlet), because common frameworks (such as Spring-mvc, or LR itself) provide one (or few) class (such as LR oob MVCPortlet you used) to wrap the portlet lifecycle, letting you to write just your code (without any need to write doview or to be worried abot dispatching of the requests inside your portlet)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same portlet class for different portlets in your plugin.

The portal container (Liferay) will create one instance of that class per portlet and initialize it with the proper configuration.

Your given snippet is the best example, why everything else would make no sense.